# Warning 1 warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'time_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data plus other errors

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
// Write a random number generator that returns a random folating point number between 0.0 and 1.0.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int rand_float(int n);

int main()

{

int n, i;
double r;

srand(time(NULL));

cout << "Enter number of dice to roll: ";
cin >> n;

for (i - 1; i <= n; i++) {
r = rand_float();
cout << r << endl;

}
return 0;

}

// Random Float Function
// 
double rand_float() {

return (double) rand () / RAND_MAX;

}
```

Now the problems / Errors  are

Warning 1   warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'time_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data

Warning 2   warning C4552: '-' : operator has no effect; expected operator with side-effect

Error   3   error C2660: 'rand_float' : function does not take 0 arguments

Comment: Does this declaration specify zero arguments: `int rand_float(int n);`?

Comment: So why did you provide a different definition and don't pass any parameter when you're calling it?

Comment: I have to add another parameter ?? I

Comment: I fixed it and I am actually doing this from a C++ book. Which is one of the example problems from the book.

Comment: Yes I still don't understand how to read them properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Warning 1 warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'time_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data

This is for  `srand(time(NULL));` where the value returned from `time` is larger than what fits into the parameter for `srand`.

This often happens for old code, as `time_t` has recently been made larger so that we don't run out of time values. It counts the number of seconds since 1970, which is by now quite a large number.

> Warning 2 warning C4552: '-' : operator has no effect; expected operator with side-effect

This is for `for (i - 1; i <= n; i++)` where the first part `i - 1` has no effect. You probably meant `i = 1`.

> Error 3 error C2660: 'rand_float' : function does not take 0 arguments

You have declared the function as `int rand_float(int n);`, so when you call it with 0 arguments, the compiler rightly believes you should pass a value for `n`.

When you later define `double rand_float()`, the compiler believes that to be a totally different function. You are allowed to overload functions with the same name but different parameters, so this is ok according to the language, but probably not what you intended.

If this is the function you want to call from `main`, you should change the declaration at the top of the code to match.